# How to generate a url from symfony2 route name in a twig template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to avoid hard-coding relative URLs in my twig templates in a Symfony2 project.

I have defined some route names in my controllers, for example:

```
@Route("/", name="homepage")
```

Is there a Twig or Symfony2 function that could help me generate links properly? Something like:

```
<a href='{{ magic_fct("homepage") }}'>Home</a>
```

would return:

```
<a href='/'>Home</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use following:

```
<a href='{{ path('homepage') }}'>Home page</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, of course you can. Take a look in [Linking to Pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages) documentation.

```
<a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">Home</a>
```